# What is the correct way to create exposed properties with defaults in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a user control with a default value for one of its properties. Here is how I am currently doing it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.HelloWorld"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="This">
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=TextToDisplay}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for HelloWorld.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HelloWorld : UserControl
    {


        public HelloWorld()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextToDisplayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextToDisplay", typeof(string),
            typeof(HelloWorld), new PropertyMetadata("Hello World!"));

        public string TextToDisplay
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextToDisplayProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextToDisplayProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when looking at the preview window it does not show my default value.

[image]

But If I put my control in something else the default text does show up.

[image]

The fact that it does not show up in the designer when I am on the `UserControl` makes me concerned that I am not doing it the correct way. Am I exposing properties to the user correctly or, if not, what is the correct way to expose a property that the user of the control can override?

Comment: I'd recommend not using the designer at all, also that is the correct way of exposing properties on user controls.

Comment: @H.B. The problem is the real control I am making is quite complex and many of the properties I am setting are Brush colors. However all the brush colors are ending up White and all my strings are empty so it is hard to get the layout right. I am having to use hardcoded values then go back and replace all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your `DependencyProperty` with the default value correctly, as can be seen in the [`DependencyProperty.Register` Method (String, Type, Type, PropertyMetadata)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PropertyMetadata Constructor (Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557329(v=vs.110).aspx)) pages on MSDN:

```
public static DependencyProperty Register(
    string name,
    Type propertyType,
    Type ownerType,
    PropertyMetadata typeMetadata
)
```

...

```
public PropertyMetadata(
    Object defaultValue
)
```

Please ignore any problems that you have with the Visual Studio WPF designer, as that has always had (and caused) problems. @ScottChamberlain, most WPF developers write XAML by hand for this exact reason... the WPF Designer is less than helpful. Each time you run your application, try taking a screen shot, or use the Snipping Tool to capture your UI. In this way, you can refer to it as you make your next changes. Repeating this process gets the job done.